# Solved : How to remove contributor from github repository

Tags: github, repository

I faced the problem when i can see a contributor but this contributor didn't contribute anything 
Tried a lot of things started with checking settings and manage access collaborators. 
Checkin commits and git shortlog 
everything was clean but account was appear in github account.
how to remove it ?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. git checkout master - So i create a new branch from main branch.
2. git checkout -m master - Renamed this branch locally
3. git push origin master - Pushed this branch
4. Switched main to master
5. removed main git push origin --delete main
6. git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master

   voila contributor are disappear,

   hopefully i helped someone to save extra time to solve this problem.

and contributors dissapear.
[image]